# Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes

Tags: git, github, heroku

One of the devs on our team has been committing and pushing directly to our heroku repo without pushing to github first and using it for version control.

I've gotten the master on github and my local synced with each and up-to-date, and this is  the version of the codebase I want to be in production. When I try `git push heroku master` I get the following error:

```
Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

What is the best way to get our codebase on heroku in-sync with github's? Would it just be a `git push heroku master -f` ?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: The error message suggest that you should pull first. Why not do that?

Comment: @EldinurtheKolibri thanks for the reply. Wouldn't that pull the code from heroku and use it to update my local, when I want the opposite? I want my local to update heroku

Comment: Do you intend to override the repo? Or do you want your changes coupled with the other changes already merged or pushed to your repository?

Comment: pull will merge the version which is remote with your version. Use that if you wish to keep the changes which currently exist on your remote. Otherwise use push --force

Comment: "One of the devs on our team has been committing and pushing directly to our heroku repo" And what now? Do you want to undo everything that dev did?

Comment: @matt yes they were mostly just package updates. Nothing important but enough to throw up an error

Comment: @Kim thanks for that. Just felt weird to use a force push on produciton

Comment: @EldinurtheKolibri just want to override - get what's on github, which is our standard, onto heroku.

Comment: Should mention that other people might run into some problems with the `--force` approach. This happens because when they pull git will try to merge their version of `master` into `heruka/master`. To avoid this they can first run `git fetch` and then `git reset --hard heruka/master`. If the changes should be kept on a new branch make a new branch at the location of their version of `master` before they do the hard reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to throw away everything the dev did on heroku, then push with force to heroku. This will cause heroku to match *exactly*, both as to state and as to history, the branch that you push.

Actually, *any* push causes the remote to match exactly, as to state and history, the branch that you push. But Git doesn't let you push to a remote unless the result would be a "fast-forward". In your case, there have been commits on heroku that you don't have, so the result would *not* be a "fast-forward" and Git blocks the push. Using force overcomes that block.